# Possible to allow client upload to S3 over https AND have a CNAME alias for the bucket?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-route53

OK, so I have a an Amazon S3 bucket to which I want to allow users to upload files directly from the client over https.

In order to do this it became apparent that I would have to change the bucket name from a format using periods to a format using dashes. So :

**my.bucket.com**

became :

**my-bucket-com**

This being required due to a limitation of https authentication which can't deal with periods in the bucket name when resolving the S3 endpoint.

So everything is peachy, except now I'd like to allow access to those files while hiding the fact that they are being stored on Amazon S3.

The obvious choice seems to be to use Route 53 zone configuration records to add a CNAME record to point my url at the bucket, given that I already have the 'bucket.com' domain :

**my.bucket.com**    >    **CNAME**    >    **my-bucket-com.s3.amazonaws.com**

However, I now seem to have hit another limitation, in that Amazon seem to insist that the name of the CNAME record must match the bucket name exactly so the above example will not work.

My temporary solution is to use a reverse proxy on an EC2 instance while traffic volumes are low. But this is not a good or long term solution as it means that all S3 access is being funneled through the proxy server causing extra server load, and data transfer charges. Not to mention the solution really isn't scalable when traffic volumes start to increase.

So is it possible to achieve both of my goals above or are they mutually exclusive?

If I want to be able to upload directly from clients over https, I can't then hide the S3 url from end users accessing that content and vice versa?

Comment: Have you considered using cloudfront?

Comment: Yes, I'm aware there might be a possible solution via cloudfront, either via a Dedicated IP or SNI, but the charges are much higher so the costs are prohibitive for the time being.

Comment: Which charges?  SNI is free.

Comment: My understanding was that using Cloudfront had a lot more charges than simply using an S3 bucket. (Not specifically SNI). I'll investigate though.

Answer (score 0):

Well there simply doesn't seem to be a straightforward way of achieving this.

There are 2 possible solutions :

1.) Put your S3 bucket behind Amazon Cloudfront - but this does incur a lot more charges, all be it with the added benefit of lower latency regional access to your content.

2.) The solution we will go with will simply be to split the bucket in to two.
One for upload from HTTPS clients **my-bucket-com**; And one for CNAME aliased access to that content **my.bucket.com**. This keeps the costs down, although it will involve extra steps in organising the content before it can be accessed.